# JavaScript/HTML Code In Variables?

Tags: javascript, function, button, var

I am designing a monopoly style digital game and want a dice rolling button so i tried this:

```
<button class="bttnrolldice" onclick="diceRoll()">Roll Dice</button><h1 id="rollresults"></h1> 
<script>
    function diceRoll() {
            var die1 =  math.ceil(math.random() * 7;
            var die2 =  math.ceil(math.random() * 7;
            document.getElementById("rollresults").innerHTML = (die1 + die2); }
</script>
```

Whenever I run the code, nothing shows up below the button. Can you give me a hand? (It might have something to do with the variables that equal js code, if so tell me how to fix this.)

Comment: I just want to Note that you are multiplying a random number between 0 and 1 by 7. Then rounding up.  That will give you number 1 through 7 inclusively. You should multiply by 6 to get 1 through 6 (although its possible to still get 0 using random())

Comment: wait could i do: document.getElementById("rollresults").innerHTML = ((die1 + 1) + (die2 + 1));?

Comment: You could use `Math.ceil(6*(1 - Math.random())); `which would include 1 through 6 but exclude 0

Comment: That Makes Sense!

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a float between 0 (inclusive) and 1  (exclusive) which is why the subtraction fixes the problem

Comment: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
See here for more info on `Math.random()`

Comment: It makes sense!

Comment: or, i could do:     Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1;        Right?

Comment: 7*.99 is less than 7 and will round down to 6. Then you add 1 and it becomes 7.

if you use 6 instead of 7 that should work though

Comment: ok but theres another problem. i opened up inspect in chrome and whenever i clicked the button it said in console:     Uncaught ReferenceError: diceRoll is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: Try putting the script before the button?

Comment: I tried using the edited version of your code, and It ran perfectly for me
Have you refreshed the page?

Comment: i have tried refreshing the page and it still doesnt work

Comment: let me try it in a separate .html file, maybe that will work

Comment: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/mgwabz6x/) 

I made a JSfiddle that uses the code in the manner it should have been edited. Does yours look different?

Comment: its still not working

Comment: You should open a separate question for that. Make sure to specify that your script tag is found within your html file, because otherwise it'll certainly get marked as a duplicate to a question I found where the error was caused by use separate files which weren't linked properly.

Comment: omfg i was missing the end curly bracket on diceRoll() :P

Comment: i accidentally deleted it after posting this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing closing parenthesis on your `Math.ceil` functions

```
<button class="bttnrolldice" onclick="diceRoll()">Roll Dice</button><h1 
id="rollresults"></h1> 
<script>
    function diceRoll() {
       var die1 =  Math.ceil(Math.random() * 7);
       var die2 =  Math.ceil(Math.random() * 7);
       document.getElementById("rollresults").innerHTML = (die1 + die2); 
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I think what he wanted was `Math.ceil(Math.random() *7 )`

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro Thx did the switch of all Math now it should be correct

Comment: Yes omg i use w3 schools.com for reference and I completely missed that part. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a right parentheses on line 4 and line 5.

When running your script in Google Chrome, press [F12] and the error will be described on the Console tab.

Comment: im on a laptop and the button for [F12] is the shortcut for airplane mode... btw im sort of new to js...

Comment: especially the math.something part of js

Comment: right click on Chrome in click inspect on the menu and it'll open the inspector. Extremely useful for JS  debugging

Comment: i see now that you told me

Answer (score 0):

Inspect element and check browser console for errors.

1. It should be "Math" instead of "math".
2. Closing parenthesis are missing in statements where die1 and die2 variables are declared.

Comment: Thank You! This Really Helped!